# stopping node-red: Unable to listen on http://127.0.0.1:1880/

Tags: beagleboneblack, node-red

I'm trying to add the dashboard nodes to node-red on a Beaglebone.

In several places on the Internet, instructions for adding features to node-red begin by saying "stop node-red". But they don't say how to do that.

On the Beaglebone Black WiFi, node-red v0.15.2 comes installed and starts automatically. So far as I can tell, the command

```
sudo node-red stop
```

should stop it, but this always results in a string of messages that end up with

```
19 May 16:13:05 - [warn] Communication server error: Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::1880
19 May 16:13:05 - [error] Unable to listen on http://127.0.0.1:1880/
19 May 16:13:05 - [error] Error: port in use
```

Nothing I've found tells how to get beyond this. The closest was a post that suggested running

```
ps -ef
```

and then killing all the `node-red` processes, but the next post in that sequence indicated that the result was that they immediately restarted themselves.

What is the correct way to stop node-red on the Beaglebone?

Or more generally, how can I add the dashboard module to the existing node-red preinstalled on the Beaglebone Black?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED is being run under SystemD as a service

use:

```
sudo service nodered stop
```

Also `node-red stop` won't stop Node-RED it will just try and start a new instance with a flow files called `stop`. The command you were probably looking for is `node-red-stop` (notice the hyphen between red and stop).

Also you do not need to stop Node-RED to install a new set of nodes, you can just install them then restart Node-RED and it will pick up the new nodes. So install and kill should work,

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

`sudo service nodered stop`
results in
`Failed to stop nodered.service: Unit nodered.service not loaded`.

`sudo node-red-stop`
results in
`sudo: node-red-stop: command not found`

What is the way to "restart Node-RED"? Does this require a reboot of the BBB? Is there a command that does this, or is the received way to do a `kill -9` of the processes found by `ps -ax | grep node-red`?